# How to increase build number in Bitbucket Pipelines?

Tags: java, maven, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a Maven project where I use buildnumber-maven-plugin for incrementing the build number. After each "mvn package" command, a variable inside buildnumber.properties file is incremented to keep tracking of current build number.

Is there a way in Bitbucket Pipelines after I run the job with "mvn package" command to commit/push the changes made by buildnumber-maven-plugin in that file? Of course, this question makes sens if running a command in butbucket pipeline can change files inside the repository.

Answer (score 1):

If any users with access to the repo are able to push to the branch you would like to commit to, you are able to commit that file back to your repository as outlined here: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-Pipelines-articles/Pushing-back-to-your-repository/ba-p/958407. Ensure to add [skip ci] so you don't create a new pipelines build for that new version bump commit.

If pushing to the branch is restricted, you can use one of these methods: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/push-back-to-your-repository-962352710.html. However, this will require providing a single user with permission to push to the branch.